# No CORS error with form but CORS error when making axios post request

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, request, cors

I was trying to post some form to backend and wanted to do with axios request, but I get cors error with axios. If I do post request with regular `<form>` it works.

This is my send async function

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('access_token', '0bf6fe96-3510-4105-ac4c-2656f1f14579');
formData.append('access_token_ttl', '10000000000000000000000000');
const res = await axios.post('myurl', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
});
```

This is form that works

```html
<form action="myurl" method="post" target="_blank">
      <input name="access_token" value="0bf6fe96-3510-4105-ac4c-2656f1f14579" type="hidden" />
      <input name="access_token_ttl" value="10000000000000000000000000" type="hidden" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Question: How to make axios request that will work?

P.S. Here's the screenshot of error[image: Cors error screenshot]

Comment: You should show the CORS error.

Comment: what is 'myurl' in axios

Comment: @morganney Added error screenshot

Comment: @Akhil it's backend server which accepts my post request

Comment: You need to configure your server to send CORS headers. Assuming you are using a node backend you can check this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: I want to know why form works, but axios doesn't :)) @morganney

Comment: Because the same origin policy only applies to JavaScript, i.e. `fetch`, `XMLHttpRequest`, etc. It has always been possible to make cross origin requests with form submissions.

Answer (score 1):

You are bumping into the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) when using axios, so in order to **read** documents, scripts, etc. cross-origin you need to use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Form submission works because cross-origin **writes** are not subject to the same origin policy. In particular,

> Cross-origin writes are typically allowed. Examples are links, redirects, and form submissions. Some HTTP requests require preflight.